# Use RemoteAttribute with ASP.NET MVC Web API using POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I wish to use System.Web.Mvc with MVC Web API.

It works fine with GET

```
[RemoteAttribute("Check", "Api/Validation", HttpMethod = "GET", ErrorMessage ="Invalid")] 
public string Name { get; set; }
```

My API Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public bool Check(string name)
{
    return false;
}
```

But when I make the **HttpMethod = "POST"** in my Network calls I get a **404 error**.

Any solutions?

Comment: Did you change the attribute above the `Check` method to `HttpPost`?

Comment: yes :) still doesn't work

Comment: Can you show the request header of the post?

Comment: [HttpPost]
public bool Check(string name)
{
    return false;
}

Comment: I mean, what does it actually post. You can use Firebug of Fiddler for that.

Comment: Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:9
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:39983
Origin:http://localhost:39983
Referer:http://localhost:39983/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.49 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:39983/api/Validation/Check
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: Looks like you are not sending the `name` parameter. Why do you want a post request anyway?

Comment: I forgot to paste that.
Form Data  name : testname

Comment: does it have to do anything with the web api routing, though the HttpGet works.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [Link](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/).  **But the parameter name comes as null.**

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Check([FromBody]string name)
{
    return false;
}
```